# RewriteRule ([A-Za-z0-9-]+) - to 404

Tags: mod-rewrite

there is my request

```
RewriteRule ^mariage/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ builder.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

My site is like:

```
www.site.com
www.site.com/mariage
www.site.com/mariage/mynewurl
```

I just want to said in my RewriteRule, if any one, from any where, type `www.site.com/mariage/SOMETHING`, redirect them to builder.php

Actually, when i do this /mariage/SOMETHING ---- it direct me to error404

Can some one revise my -code please? thx !

Comment: If you didn't realize, in my builder.php i will use the 'SOMETHING' to  different request by get method.

Comment: its done, i need to put my htacces at the root and my builder.php at the root, and not in /mariage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
RewriteRule ^mariage/(\.+)$ builder.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```